# Не создается таблица средствами PHP в БД SQLite3

Tags: sqlite3, база-данных, php

Всех с Новым 2015 годом и доброго времени суток.

Образовалась некоторая проблема. Использую OpenServer для изучения PHP OOP. Все работало нормально, до начала совместного использования PHP 5.4 c SQLite3. Задача такая: создать файл БД и в нем создать пару таблиц. 
Файл создается без проблем, но вот запросы на создание таблиц никак не желают выполняться. Есть подозрение на настройки OpenServer, хотя, возможно, и ошибки в коде. Код прилагается:

```
class NewsDB implements INewsDB{

function saveNews($title, $category, $description, $source){}
function getNews(){}
function deleteNews($id){}

const DB_NAME = 'C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite.local\news.db';
protected $_db;

public function __construct(){
    if(is_file(self::DB_NAME)){
        $this->_db = new SQLite3(self::DB_NAME);}
    else{
        $this->_db = new SQLite3(self::DB_NAME); 
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE msgs(
                                     id               INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                     title            TEXT,
                                     category      INTEGER,
                                    description    TEXT,
                                    source          TEXT,
                                    datetime       INTEGER)";
        $this->_db->exec($sgl) or die($this->_db->lastErrorMsg());  
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE category(
                                    id          INTEGER,
                                    name        TEXT)';
        $this->_db->exec($sgl) or die($this->_db->lastErrorMsg());  
        $sql = "INSERT INTO category(id, name)
                            SELECT 1 as id, 'Политика' as name
                            UNION SELECT 2 as id, 'Культура' as name
                            UNION SELECT 3 as id, 'Спорт' as name ";
        $this->_db->exec($sgl) or die($this->_db->lastErrorMsg());}
}

public function __destruct(){
    unset($this->_db);
}
}

$news = new NewsDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить команду в двух строчках

```
$this->_db->exec($sgl) or die($this->_db->lastErrorMsg());
```

на

```
$this->_db->query($sgl) or die($this->_db->lastErrorMsg());
```